# jQuery : Need extract the value as another array

Tags: jquery

Need to convert in jQuery [Medical: 39, Camera: 2, Surgical: 1] to [39,2,1].

Please snippet . Thanks

Comment: The first is invalid structure. Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: Hello, please read the following and ask a question accordingly: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , [what can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think this  `[Medical: 39, Camera: 2, Surgical: 1]`  should not be an array but an object, so the syntax should be like this: `{Medical: 39, Camera: 2, Surgical: 1}` Or like this: `[{Medical: 39}, {Camera: 2}, {Surgical: 1}]`.

Then to transform it try this:

```js
var obj={Medical: 39, Camera: 2, Surgical: 1};
var arr=[];
$.each(obj,function(index,element){
  arr.push(element);
});

console.log(arr);

//OR like this

var obj2=[{Medical: 39}, {Camera: 2}, {Surgical: 1}];
var arr2=[];
$.each(obj2,function(index,element){
  $.each(element,function(index2,element2){
    arr2.push(element2);
  });
});

console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could be `[{Medical: 39}, {Camera: 2}, {Surgical: 1}]` too.

Comment: @LucasCosta true, should I give a solution to this case also ?

Comment: Thanks Mehdi, i got cleared the fix

Comment: @KarthikeyanThiagarajan why did you disapproved my answer, is it wrong ?

Comment: Hai, Changed, I have less reputation to up-vote you. Anyway thanks